# TLS1.2 negotiation fails within a 4.5.1 application when .net Framework 4.7.2 is installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest, tls1.2

we are currently experiencing an issue with our web based application. It runs well under any OS win2k12 R2 and higher on an IIS. The application is compiled targeting .net Framework 4.5.1. Whilst we are aware of newer .NET Framework versions, we struggle with the update due to several inconvenient 3rd party dependencies.

Recently, Microsoft released KBs which implicitly installed .NET Framework 4.7.2. It is customers with these updates installed, that face a major issue right now.

The following code, while oversimplified, contains all necessary information.

```
private HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
{
            lock (Statics._lockObject)
            {

                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
                SecurityProtocolType tempProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;

                //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;   // Magic Number equals SecurityProtocolType.Tls1.2 
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CheckSSL;
                try
                {
                    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                }
                finally
                {
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = tempProtocol;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = null;
                }
                return httpResponse;
            }
        }
```

When executing this on a system that has .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed, we get the following error within the `GetResponse()`call:

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

```
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

and the inner exception:

"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

`at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)`

Uninstalling the aforementioned KBs and thus, .NET Framework 4.7.2, does help, but is no option for our customer base.

So far, the other options we tried are:

setting registry keys as followed:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

whilst commenting out the explicit setting of tls 1.2 in the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property 
(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#schusestrongcrypto)

setting appcontextswitches:

Switch.System.ServiceModel.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions
Switch.System.ServiceModel.DisableUsingServicePointManagerSecurityProtocols

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element)

So far, we are unable to get any change in regard to the exception thrown. 
Can anyone point us in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Update:**

Due to recommendation in the comments, we made a couple of wireshark traces.

*Without* Framework 4.7.2 installed, our application negotiates - just as our code sample suggests - tls 1.2 successfully with the server application:

[image: .NET Framework 4.5.1, SecurityProtocol == Tls12]

Afterwards, we changed the code to specifically set tls 1.1 only to confirm that setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol makes an impact an we see, to no surprise, the application fails to negotiate tls 1.1:

[image: .NET Framework 4.5.1, SecurityProtocol == Tls11]

Now for the fun part, we installed .NET Framework 4.7.2 again, resetted the code to specifically say

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

and traced the call again. Now, to our surprise, the app tries to negotiate tls 1.0, which of course fails:

[image: .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed, SecurityProtocol == Tls12]

Afterwards, we specifically disabled tls 1.0 on the OS via:

```
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client

"Enabled"=dword:0000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001 `
```

Looking at Wireshark again, the application tried to negotiate ssl3.0. Back to the registry and specifically disabling that one as well, there was no more ClientHello shown in Wireshark and the exception said, that no mutual algorithm could be found to connect to the server.

Comment: This may sound like an odd question, but which clients have you tried? My only thought is the updates could have introduced a new TLS Ciper Suite that may not be working with the browser/client PC. Chrome, for example uses its own TLS logic, while IE and .NET code matches Windows' settings. I'd be curious to see if they produce different results in your error. Doing a network capture/wireshark may also provide some insight to which protocols are being negotiated. Comparing the good to the bad negotiation may indicate which part of the handshake is causing it to fail.

Comment: Is it possible that the server does NOT support TLS1.2? That would explain the error.

Another option is to look at Wireshark traces to see details of the failure ...

Comment: Thanks, mates! I have updated the question with our wireshark traces.

Comment: Install IIsCrypto on your server to check which TLS versions are enabled on your server , from which application is running , ensure the remote party(webservice or DB server) also implement TLS 1.2

Comment: @ABDmaverick thank you for the hint; IISCrypto tells me factory default von the computer from which the application is running (Win 10). I fiddled around a bit, setting the "best practices" option, which only left TLS 1.0 - 1.2 enabled, still tried to negotiate TLS 1.0, I restricted the protocols to ONLY TLS 1.2 and apart from almost all applications on my computer crashing, my app did not negotiate anything and the exception thrown says that there was no mutual algorithm to go with... From different computers, the server can be accessed via TLS 1.2 with ease through the above routine.

Comment: So does the app work with TLS 1.2 + dotnet 4.7 succssfully ?

Comment: yes, it does. It's .NET Framework 4.7.2 which somehow changes a detail in the communication process. Please note that in all scenarios the application is still compiled using 4.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting these registry settings:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 
   Value: SchUseStrongCrypto 
     Data: 1

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server    
   Value: Enabled
     Data: 0
   Value: DisabledByDefault
     Data: 1
```

After that, before making your HTTPWebRequest include the ServicePointManager change:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

That should force your application to TLS 1.2. I didn't see anything saying you'd tried all the above at once, and doing this worked for us.

Comment: Hi Phen, thank you for your comment! Just hours bevor you posted your answer, we did find out that setting the "SchUseStrongCrypto" key only in the Wow6432Node did not suffice to orchestrate the .NET Framework. ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol now defaults to Tls1.0 | Tls 1.1 | Tls 1.2. Works like a charm!